# How to place HashSets INSIDE of a HashMap?

Tags: java

I'm trying to place a String (the individual words) and an int (their HashCodes) into a HasMap. I'm really struggling when it comes to placing items inside.

```
// These approaches won't even run the code properly. 
map.put(word.hashCode(), word);

// This type of approach makes my code work, but it's obviously not adding the words in.
map.put(word.hashCode(), new HashSet<String>());
```

I've been trying a lot of different funky things here, but I can't really work out how to properly add the individual words into the map. Can someone help me understand how to first place it into the HashSet so it can be put into the map?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Assign004{
public static void main(String args[]){

    // INT = HASHCODE
    // STRING = WORD
    Map<Integer, HashSet<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<String>>();

    // READ WORDS AND PLACE THEM INTO THE MAP
    readFile(map);
}

public static void readFile(Map<Integer, HashSet<String>> map){
    String word = null;

    try{
        File file = new File("src/Assign004_FILE.txt");
        Scanner r = new Scanner(file);

        while(r.hasNext()){

            /* *******************************************************
                      TEST CODE. TO CHECK IF IT'S READING IN THE WORDS 
            word = r.next();
            int hash = word.hashCode();
            System.out.print(word);
            System.out.print(": " + hash + "\n"); 
            ******************************************************** */

            word = r.next();
            map.put(word.hashCode(), new HashSet<String>());
            System.out.print(map);
        }
        r.close();

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("ERROR OPENING FILE");
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `hashCode` explicitly? Do you actually need to work directly with the hashcodes? It seems unlikely.

Comment: First, get the set with `Set<String> set = map.get(word.hashCode());`, then insert the element into the set with `set.add(word);`.

Comment: Can you give us a high level overview of what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: Please read about the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: If you're using Java 1.7 or higher then the diamond operator makes the code little more readable and best to use collection interface not its implementation in the type; i.e. `Map<Integer, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>()`

Answer (score 1):

So you have this.

```
map.put(word.hashCode(), new HashSet<String>());
```

And you want to put a word into the set, then stick the set into the map?

Then you need to break up the operations.

1. Make a `Set` object
2. Put `word` into the `Set`
3. Put the set (containing the word) into the map.

Feel free to comment / edit your question to clarify what the actual goal is, though.

Comment: The first two steps could also be combined into just [`Collections.singleton(word)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton-T-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare HashSet outside first, then you can put it in the map.

```
    public class Helloworld {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Array with duplicates to check 

    String[] words = {"tomorrow", "today", "yesterday", "tomorrow", "today"};

    Map<Integer, HashSet<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<String>>();

    for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++) {

    HashSet<String> word = new HashSet<String>();

    word.add(words[i]);

    map.put(word.hashCode(), word);

    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Can we get the bigger picture though? haschCode can generate collision. It is used to make efficient searches which is already done by the implementation of HashMap and HashSet. I don't think it's a good idea to use haschode as a key in HashMap